# How to multiply data of two columns for third column in datagridview

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, datagridview

I want to multiply the data of two columns and show it in the third column.

For example:

```
1st Column: Quantity
2nd Column: Rate
3rd Column: Price
```

I want to multiply as user enters the data for quantity and rate like `Quantity=2`, `rate=50`automatically in price column I want `100` to be appear.

Simultaneously I want to division as user enters the data for quantity and rate like `Price=100`, `rate=50`automatically in Quantity column I want `2` to be appear.

And
 when a user enters the data for quantity and rate like `Price=100`, `Quantity=2`automatically in Rate column I want `50` to be appear.

This three will happen in a same datagridview. User only enter any two field within this three and third will come automatically.

Using C#, VS2008, SQL 2008

```
private void dataGridView2_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) 
{ 
    int quantity,rate; 
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView2.Rows.Count; i++) 
    { 
        if(int.TryParse(dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString(), out quantity) && int.TryParse(dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString(), out rate)) 
        { 
             int price = quantity * rate; dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value = price.ToString(); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

I write this code. There shows a error. Object reference not set to an instance of an object on

```
if(int.TryParse(dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString(), out quantity) && int.TryParse(dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString(), out rate))
```

this line.

---

[image]

I want to do like this. User can fill any 2 field among this 3. And third will take automatically.

Comment: What if the `rate` and `quantity` are already `50` and `2` respectively but user enters `150` into the `Price`? How do we update the other 2 columns? Update `rate` and `quantity` as `50` and `3` respectively or `3` and `50` respectively? or `15` and `10` respectively? Your problem is in fact a little unclear. In context of `Binding`, that even becomes more complex.

Answer (score 2):

handle the `CellEndEdit` event of your gridview. And in that event calculate and assign the value to the third column

something like

```
private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        int quantity,rate;
        if (int.TryParse(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["quantity"].Value.ToString(), out quantity) && int.TryParse(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["rate"].Value.ToString(), out rate))
        {
            int price = quantity * rate;
            dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["price"].Value = price.ToString();
         }
    }
```

Comment: @AnimeshGhosh same as above. You only need to add an if statement to check which 2 columns have value and based on that you assign the value to the third column.

Comment: private void dataGridView2_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
int quantity,rate;
         for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView2.Rows.Count; i++)
         {
             if(int.TryParse(dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString(), out quantity) && int.TryParse(dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString(), out rate))
                {
                    int price = quantity * rate;
                    dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value = price.ToString();
                }
            }
 
        }
Error:obj reference not set

Comment: do you want to perform multiply operation once all rows  data is entered or cell by cell

Comment: @AnimeshGhosh post your code in the question and mention the line that is giving object reference.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellendedit.aspx

Comment: what is null? Either Cells[1] or Cells[2] is null that is why you are getting exception

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution for you.

```
double s = Convert.ToDouble(DataGridShowAddedProducts.Rows[0].Cells[2].Value);
        double s1 = Convert.ToDouble(DataGridShowAddedProducts.Rows[0].Cells[2].Value);
        double s13 = s1 * s;
        MessageBox.Show(s13.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
decimal s=0, s1=0,s13 = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j< dgvsaledetails.Rows.Count; ++j)
        {
            s = Convert.ToDecimal(dgvsaledetails.Rows[j].Cells[6].Value);
            s1 = Convert.ToDecimal(dgvsaledetails.Rows[j].Cells[10].Value);
            s13 = s * s1;
            dgvsaledetails.Rows[j].Cells["amount"].Value = s13.ToString();

        }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

usually see error parameter column
So dont use header name of column but only for column name as see

```
decimal qty = 0, price = 0, amount = 0;
for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView2.Rows.Count; ++j)
{
              // cloumn9=qty
  qty = Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView2.Rows[j].Cells["Column9"].Value);
// column4 = price
  price = Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView2.Rows[j].Cells["Column4"].Value);
  amount = qty * price;
// cloumn7 = amount
 dataGridView2.Rows[j].Cells["Column7"].Value = s13.ToString();

            }
```