# how to calculate datagridview column?

Tags: c#

I am a new user in `C# winform` and also new user in this site, too

I have a `datagridview` with 4 columns

```
      No.     proname           price        qty      total

      1        fish               0.0         1         -
      2        tofu               0.0         1         -
```

Data in example like that, I give the default price and qty like above total is empty. Now I need to `cellclick` on column price to new input value on currentrow after I gave the new value I leave it by press Enter key or anyway just leave the cell I need the `price*qty = total` on currentrow. Or opposite I new input the qty to 2... and price not "0.0" then `Price * qty=total`

But if I edit on other cell not two of above the event do nothing.

How do I multiply that ?

Anybody can help me in better solution?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should look at "data binding" and have one property of your model `Total` that return the total value based on the `Price` and `Quantity` properties

Comment: Winforms or WPF? Do you use `DataTable`? Do you use data binding? Edit the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to multiply data of two columns for third column in datagridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18650856/how-to-multiply-data-of-two-columns-for-third-column-in-datagridview)

Answer (score 1):

In the code Behind use this

```
int.Parse(row.Cells[3].Value.toString()) * int.Parse(row.Cells[4].Value.toString())
```

Your Method look like this

```
private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        int quantity,rate;
        if (int.TryParse(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["quantity"].Value.ToString(), out quantity) && int.TryParse(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["rate"].Value.ToString(), out rate))
        {
            int price = quantity * rate;
            dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["price"].Value = price.ToString();
         }
    }
```

[For more find reference here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22728901/how-to-multiply-data-gridview-two-columns-and-show-the-result-in-another-column)

[Another Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18650856/how-to-multiply-data-of-two-columns-for-third-column-in-datagridview)

Answer (score 0):

Here is exactly what you're looking for. [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38928260/6682254)

The answer given by this guy is really well explained and it's not going to be hard doing  the implementation.

> By this way the "Total" column is automatically maintained via an
>   Expression which means you cannot manually do anything to that column.